# Any RSpec like tool for Erlang?

Tags: ruby, rspec, erlang, bdd

Is there something like RSpec `describe` `it` framework for Erlang?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you seen espec: https://github.com/lucaspiller/espec? Seems like it can have syntax like

```
describe("#generate_headers", fun() ->
    it("should generate Host and User-Agent headers", fun() ->
        [
            {"Host", "api.twitter.com"},
            {"User-Agent", "Twerl"}
        ] = stream_client_util:generate_headers()
    end)
end).
```

Comment: Looks like this project is abandoned now, unfortunately. I like RSpec's way of organizing/grouping tests (nested). There doesn't seem to be a replacement really.

Comment: it should support nesting now